# Determining expiration date based on list of months in which to refresh

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, datetime

I have a list of months in which users are required to update some data. I want to determine at what date they should have updated their data. They must update in March, May and August. If today is March, I want to get back the 1st of March. If today is February, I want to get back last year's August. In reality the list wouldn't be hardcoded.

I do have some working code, but I wonder if there is a simpler / more elegant of writing this (the `GetCheckDate` method).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var listOfMonths = new List<int?> {3, 5, 8};
        Console.WriteLine(GetCheckDate(listOfMonths,
            new DateTime(2014, 2, 1))); // expect 2013-08-01
        Console.WriteLine(GetCheckDate(listOfMonths,
            new DateTime(2014, 3, 1))); // expect 2014-03-01
        Console.WriteLine(GetCheckDate(listOfMonths,
            new DateTime(2014, 7, 1))); // expect 2014-05-01
        Console.WriteLine(GetCheckDate(null,
            new DateTime(2014, 7, 1))); // expect 2013-07-1
        Console.WriteLine(GetCheckDate(new List<int?>(),
            new DateTime(2014, 7, 1))); // expect 2013-07-1
    }

    private static DateTime GetCheckDate(IEnumerable<int?> listOfMonths,
        DateTime curDate)
    {
        DateTime result = curDate.AddYears(-1);
        if (listOfMonths == null) return result;
        listOfMonths = listOfMonths.ToList();
        if (!listOfMonths.Any()) return result;

        listOfMonths = listOfMonths.OrderByDescending(m => m).ToList();
        var greatestSmallerThan =
            listOfMonths.FirstOrDefault(m => m <= curDate.Month)
            ?? listOfMonths.FirstOrDefault(m => m > curDate.Month);
        result = new DateTime(
            greatestSmallerThan.Value <= curDate.Month
                ? curDate.Year : curDate.Year - 1, greatestSmallerThan.Value, 1);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if list of months is empty?

Comment: This is not complete code. If the list is empty, I'll return `curDate.AddYears(-1)` (edited). What I'd like to know is how to efficiently determine the date.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you to improve naming:

- `months` instead of `listOfMonths` because its not list, and its better not to include variable type description into name
- `date` instead of `curDate` - its better to avoid abbreviations, also current method should not care whether moth is current or not - it just search previous month from given months
- Possibly I would rename method to something like `GetPreviousMonth`

Also I don't see any need to have nullable type for months sequence. It should have integers. If month exist in list, then you can avoid sorting - so do this check first. Thus you are not going to add/remove month, then saving ordered sequence to array is little better:

```
public static DateTime GetCheckDate(IEnumerable<int> months, DateTime date)
{
    if (month == null || !months.Any() || months.Contains(date.Month))
        return date.AddDays(1 - date.Day);

    var orderedMonths = months.OrderByDescending(m => m).ToArray();
    if (date.Month > orderedMonths.First())
        return new DateTime(date.Year, orderedMonths.First(), 1);

    if (date.Month < orderedMonths.Last())            
        return new DateTime(date.Year - 1, orderedMonths.First(), 1);

    return new DateTime(date.Year, orderedMonths.First(m => m < date.Month), 1);
}
```

But I also prefer readability on first place (performance should be improved only if its a problem) so I would go with Max and Min month instead of sorting them and keeping in mind what is Last and what is First:

```
public static DateTime GetCheckDate(IEnumerable<int> months, DateTime date)
{
    if (month == null || !months.Any() || months.Contains(date.Month))          
        return date.AddDays(1 - date.Day);            

    if (months.Max() < date.Month)
        return new DateTime(date.Year, months.Max(), 1);

    if (date.Month < months.Min())            
        return new DateTime(date.Year - 1, months.Max(), 1);

    return new DateTime(date.Year, months.Where(m => m < date.Month).Max(), 1);
}
```

If I would continue making it more readable, then following extension methods would be useful:

```
public static DateTime FirstDayOfMonth(this DateTime date, int month = 0)
{
    return new DateTime(date.Year, month == 0 ? date.Month : month, 1);
}

public static DateTime PreviousYear(this DateTime date)
{
    return date.AddYears(-1);
}
```

Now whole method is very easy to understand:

```
public static DateTime GetCheckDate(IEnumerable<int> months, DateTime date)
{
    if (month == null || !months.Any() || months.Contains(date.Month))
        return date.FirstDayOfMonth();

    if (months.Max() < date.Month)
        return date.FirstDayOfMonth(months.Max());

    if (date.Month < months.Min())
        return date.PreviousYear().FirstDayOfMonth(months.Max());

    return date.FirstDayOfMonth(months.Where(m => m < date.Month).Max());
}
```

Comment: Because I originally posted my question on StackOverflow, I simplified the code. In reality, it's not a `List<int>`, it's a list of an anonymous type containing the month and a number of months of slack time. The list is created from an xml string. If March is the month determined, it's ok if they've updated their data in the indicated number of months before that date. Should I write sample code that reflects the real code more?

Comment: Also, if `date` is 2014-09-01, your (first) method returns 2014-03-01 where I'd expect 2014-08-01. The second method doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @comecme hold on, I'll check. Also do you have some problems to apply this code to anonymous types?

Comment: I've updated my question to be more like my real code. I'm using a class `MonthSlack` here. In my code it's an anonymous type, but I don't think that would make a difference. I can't use `months.Max()` now. Could use `months.Max(m => m.Month)`, but I'd still need the actual `MonthSlack` where Month has that max value. If you want to rewrite my new code, I guess you'd better do that in a new answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`DateTime.AddMonths`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to simplify the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var checkDate = curDate.AddMonths(-i))
    if (listOfMonths.Contains(checkDate.Month)) {
        return new DateTime(checkDate.Year, checkDate.Month, 1);
    }
}
```